# How can I import a variable from a component to another ? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, antd

So, Im trying to split my trigger from the sider, so I can use it in another component without lose binding.

At first, trigger was inside Sider and working properly, but i really need trigger as a component working apart sider for put him in another header component.

And I am pretty new to react. Thanks!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Layout, Menu } from 'antd';
import {
    UserOutlined,
    VideoCameraOutlined,
    UploadOutlined
} from '@ant-design/icons';

const { Sider } = Layout;
const AppSider = () => {
    const collapsed = useState(false);
    const toggleCollapsed = () => setCollapsed(!collapsed);
    return (
        <div>
            <Sider trigger={null} collapsible collapsed={collapsed}>
                <div className="logo" />
                <Menu theme="dark" mode="inline" defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}>
                    <Menu.Item key="1" icon={<UserOutlined />}>
                        nav 1
                    </Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item key="2" icon={<VideoCameraOutlined />}>
                        nav 2
                    </Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item key="3" icon={<UploadOutlined />}>
                        nav 3
                    </Menu.Item>
                </Menu>
            </Sider>
        </div>

    );
}
export default AppSider
```

my Trigger:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Button } from 'antd';
import {
    MenuUnfoldOutlined,
    MenuFoldOutlined 
} from '@ant-design/icons';

const Trigger = () => {
   
    return(
        <Button  type="primary"  onClick={toggleCollapsed}   style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
         {React.createElement(collapsed ? MenuUnfoldOutlined : MenuFoldOutlined)}
    </Button>
    );
}

export default Trigger;
```

Comment: I think your question will get downvoted if you not change the wording to "How can I render one component from within another with React?" That is what I understand you to be asking here.

Answer (score 0):

import the trigger component into the sider like this `import Trigger from "THE-PATH-TO-TRIGGER-COMPONENT"` and then you can use it like this anywhere you want.

```
<Trigger toggleCollapsed={toggleCollapsed} collapsed={collapsed} />
```

you should also send the `toggleCollapsed` and `collapsed` to the trigger component as a prop because it needs them